# Jquery to get parameter Id from MVC url?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, url, parameters

I have the following url : http://www.xzy.com/AMS/Audit/Agency/10017397

I need to strip out the id: 10017397 from this url?

I tried:

```
  function GetURLParameter(sParam) {
            var sPageURL = window.location.search.substring(1);
            var sURLVariables = sPageURL.split('&');
            for (var i = 0; i < sURLVariables.length; i++)
            {
                var sParameterName = sURLVariables[i].split('=');
                if (sParameterName[0] == sParam)
                {
                    return sParameterName[1];
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This will help you see [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/23mkE/1/)

```
function GetURLParameter() {
                var sPageURL = window.location.href;
                var indexOfLastSlash = sPageURL.lastIndexOf("/");

                if(indexOfLastSlash>0 && sPageURL.length-1!=indexOfLastSlash)
                    return sPageURL.substring(indexOfLastSlash+1);
                else 
                   return 0;
            }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try using this regular expression to get the last number off a string: http://jsfiddle.net/2AKDQ/2/

```
var URL = "http://www.xzy.com/AMS/Audit/Agency/10017397";
var number = URL.match(/(\d+)$/g);
```

But you'll really need to provide more information.. Is the numeric value always at the end of the string? Or if not, is it always at position 4? Is the string always the same apart from the number?

Answer (score 0):

here you go it extracts only the numbers from the string

```
var thestring="http://www.xzy.com/AMS/Audit/Agency/10017397";
your_required_no= thestring.match(/\d+\.?\d*/g)
alert(your_required_no)
```

If you are sure your url will have only the numbers after the last `/` then try above one