# How to get the current page in view?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

Is there a way to access the "current page number" (which is a parameter in a method inside my controller class) inside a view without sending it from controller via the `View(modelWithCurrentPageAndOtherParameters)` method? Does something like `Context.Current.Page` exist?

Example:

If I access this url for example: https://example.com/products/page/3

How can i get the number 3 within the view?

Comment: Can you elaborate? If you're within a view then you *are* the current page

Comment: @DiskJunky added to my question. Let me know if it's not clear enough.

Comment: This might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16971079/jquery-to-get-parameter-id-from-mvc-url

Comment: @WillyDavidJr your suggestion gets it in javascript and i need to get it on the server side with c#.

Answer (score 0):

please try either of the following solutions

```
@Request.Params["paramName"] or
@ViewContext.RouteData.Values["id"]
```

Comment: I get this: "The name 'Request' does not exist in the current context".

Comment: @JedatKinports, that'd be `Context.Current.Request`.

Comment: 'HttpContext' does not contain a definition for 'Current' and no extension method 'Current' accepting a first argument of type 'HttpContext' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) Which reference am I missing?

Comment: Assuming you are using Razor engine for your templates, you can access like @Request.Params["paramName"]

Comment: Yes I'm using Razor, `@if(){}` works without problems. But i still get that error i posted before. :(

Comment: in my API, i have a default home controller and default index method like the following:
public ActionResult Index(int id)
        {
            return View();
        }
then i can get the id value like the following. if it solves your problem, please mark it as required answer
@ViewContext.RouteData.Values["id"]

Comment: I tried both but none is working. They work with .NET Framework. I tested. But i need this for .NET Core. Are you using the .NET Core or .NET Framework?

Comment: Yes, i am using .net framework. for .net core, please refer to the following stack overflow question:   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42046781/how-to-get-value-of-id-in-url-from-razor-view-in-asp-net-core

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the request parameter, you'd have to set it in the controller either via the view's model or via the `ViewBag` in order for it to be accessible to the view. E.g.;

```
public ActionResult Test(string parameterName)
{
    ViewModelSample model = new ViewModelSample();
    model.Value = parameterName;
    return View(model);
}
```

and in your view you'd have;

```
@model ViewModelSample

<span>@Model.Value</span>
```

Alternatively you could have in your controller;

```
ViewBag.ParameterName = parameterName;
```

And in the view;

```
<span>@ViewBag.ParameterName</span>
```